# Delete array from list of arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want delete the array from list of arrays in that way

```
i = np.array([1,2])
facets = [np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])]
```

I want remove an element

```
facets.remove(np.array(i[0],i[1]))
```

but obtain an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-c0d040653e23> in <module>()
----> 1 facets.remove([i[0],i[2]])

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there a way to solve that problem?

Comment: The declaration of `facets` throws an error.

Comment: yep=) a mistake=) I wanted to simplify code example.

Comment: You're code still doesn't parse. The last line needs to be `facets.remove(np.array([i[0],i[1]]))`.

Comment: I've edited it now, sorry. That doesn't matter for the problem -- in common I have a long list of arrays of size 2, and I wanna remove an array, using another array

Comment: Right, but we can't reproduce your error quickly or test solutions if your code doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `all()` to compare the list element-by-element to the element you want to remove and return all that do not match. Note that this removes all elements of your list that match the array you want to remove.

```
[ x for x in facets if not (x==i).all()]
```

Comment: But what do I have actually do? 
     `(facets == np.array(i[0], i[1])).any()`

returns False, but facets contains it

Comment: I don't get what you mean, just try the code that I've written. It's a list comprehension; it should return a list of arrays.

Comment: I mean that I need exactly do that: `[ x for x in facets if not (x == [i[0], i[1]])` and I thought it will work with `... (x == np.array(i[0], i[1])`

Comment: It works, as long as you create your array correctly: `[ x for x in facets if not (x==np.array([i[0],i[1]])).all()]`

Comment: Thank you! I also have the same problem with `.index` function. Does it mean that it's hard to use built-in functions for some complicated lists?

Comment: @Maxim.K. Some built-in functions don't work well if you have a list of numpy arrays. Really, it would probably be easier to use a 3d numpy array

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't behave in the same way that `remove` does. This will remove all elements equal, rather than just the first. This may be ideal in many cases. It also creates a new list, which may not be desired. Also, the general approach of mixing lists and numpy arrays seems dubious.

Comment: @o_o Yes, I mentioned that it removes all matching elements. And I agree that using lists and arrays is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 1]
ls.remove(1)
```

This code does something like:

1. Iterate through the elements of `ls`.
2. Check whether each element is equal to `1`.
3. If it does, it pops that element, and breaks iteration.

In step 2, your code is trying to compare two numpy arrays like `array1 == array2`. The problem is that numpy returns an array of truth values for this comparison.

```
>>> np.array([1,2]) == np.array([1,3])
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

So, you're going to have to implement your own remove-like method.

```
def remove_from_array(base_array, test_array):
    for index in range(len(base_array)):
        if np.array_equal(base_array[index], test_array):
            base_array.pop(index)
            break
    raise ValueError('remove_from_array(array, x): x not in array')
```

Usage:

```
i = np.array([1,2])
facets = [np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])]
remove_from_array(facets, i)

print facets # [array([3, 4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
facets.remove(np.array(i[0],i[1]))
```

This worked for me as follows :

```
>>> i = list([1,2])
>>> facets = [list([1,2]),list([3,4])]
>>> facets.remove(list([i[0],i[1]]))
>>> facets
[[3, 4]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have a list of np.arrays not a list of lists. That doesn't work if you replace  `facets = [np.array(1,2), np.array(3,4)]`